# Persist App Cookies to WebBrowserTask

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am struggling with something and I am not sure if this is possible or not with the current WP7 API.  Basically my WP7 App uses WebRequest class to issue web requests to log into a third party website using username and password credentials of the user.  I store session state/cookie information in a CookieContainer object so that I can make further requests for data from the web site and this all works fine, pretty standard scenario so far.

But what I would like to do now is offer a link to take the user to the secure area of web site without needing the user to log in again when accessing the site from the phones browser.  If I simply call a webbrowsertask it takes me to the website but the browser has no knowledge of the cookies I stored in my app so the web site redirects the user to the log in page.  What I need/want to be able to do is provide the CookieContainer object I have stored from my app requests through to the webbrowsertask so that I can go straight to the page I want.

```
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
webBrowserTask.URL = "https://www.xxx.com/loginarea";
webBrowserTask.Show();
```

Any suggestions/thoughts on how I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get the cookies to the main IE web browser

However, if you were prepared to host the browser control inside your app, then you should be able to inject the cookie values using javascript.